# Complex Query to get else DAYNAME from my table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have here complex script in which will output log and dayname
so my **(SELECT IF(DAYNAME(effectiveDate) ='Sunday' ,CONCAT('Sunday',log)**
is working, but in else i want to output if the user have no time. the output should be only the word SUNDAY because the condition if the user is not log then SUNDAY ONLY, if the user is LOG then LOG + the sunday word

[image: this is the output of my script]

```
SELECT effectiveDate,

(SELECT

(case



when note ='REGULAR LOGGED'
THEN (SELECT IF(DAYNAME(effectiveDate) ='Sunday' ,CONCAT('Sunday',log), (SELECT DAYNAME(effectiveDate) ='Sunday' FROM schedules) )
FROM schedules WHERE schedules.effectiveDate = timesheet.date AND schedules.empid = employees.empid)


end)


FROM timesheet
WHERE
schedules.effectiveDate = timesheet.date
AND counter = '1' and empid='40'  AND timeStatus='OK' GROUP BY date ) am1,


DATE_FORMAT(effectiveDate, '%W') as DAY_OF_WEEK



FROM schedules
LEFT JOIN timesheet ON schedules.effectiveDate = timesheet.date
AND schedules.empid = timesheet.empid
LEFT JOIN employees ON schedules.empid = employees.empid

WHERE schedules.empid='40' and YEAR(effectiveDate) ='2017' and MONTH(effectiveDate) ='1' AND DATE_FORMAT(effectiveDate, '%W') ='Sunday'
GROUP BY effectiveDate ORDER BY effectiveDate ASC
```